# Why Does Scaffolded ASP.NET Core Controller return NoContent() and not OKSuccess()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build a 100% standard REST service with ASP.NET Core 2.0.  When I scaffold the controllers using the Visual Studio 2017 tooling, it builds an awesome async controller with well written GET,PUT,POST and DELETE methods.

I'm wondering why though the Put returns NoContent and not OK.  Seems add.

```
   // PUT: api/Sessions/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutSessionRec([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] SessionRec sessionRec)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != sessionRec.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(sessionRec).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!SessionRecExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

DELETE GET and POST all return 200's (OK)

Comment: [HTTP Code 204: No Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204): *"The HTTP 204 No Content success status response code indicates that **the request has succeeded, but that the client doesn't need to go away from its current page**."*

Comment: Thanks @RonBeyer  Axios (my JavaScript spa rest library) is treating a 204 as an error which i'm researching why now (seems that wrong).

Comment: Which javascript library u r using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common response of `PUT` is '204' (No content), it indicates than your request is successfully processed and you do not need to redirect to another page,

BTW, the `2xx` response is success response and you should treated as same.